# Catching uncaught exception in async function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, exception, async-await

Currently I have code such as:

```
window.onerror = function() {
    // Send some debug info about the defective error handling,
    // so that it may be fixed
};
```

To handle otherwise uncaught exceptions. Unfortunately this does not work for an `async` function. For example, if we call `fooasync()` below:

```
async function fooasync() {
    throw 'Catch me!';
}
```

Then the exception (if otherwise uncaught) won't be caught by the `window.onerror` catch-all...

I've done the requisite searching and have mostly come accross the answer, "it's not possible and anyway, it would be bad and you should catch it explicitly." I agree of course, but what if you have accidentally not wrapped an `async` function in a `try...catch`?

As an example of a valid use-case: I use the `window.onerror` handler to send me a debug email to let me know that something has gone horribly wrong for the person using my whatever. Great, at least I'm aware of the problem: Now I can fix the issue (and even fix the broken error-handling with an explicit `try...catch`). However, in the case of the `async` function, I have no way to even become aware of the issue (other than someone complaining that it's not working the way it's supposed to).

Is it possible to catch these `async` uncaught exceptions?

Comment: There are no uncaught exceptions in `async function`s - they always get caught and will reject the promise. Which then might cause an *unhandled rejection* - search for that term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to `onerror`, there is `onunhandledrejection`, which will be triggered if a Promise rejects and no handler is attached to it. [Read on on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunhandledrejection)